# My HTML project loads indefinitely while trying to implement a time function

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I've been working on a project for my family to check whether our grandmother (who is leaving for a year long trip with some of her friends) is in the country or not.

This may seem stupid, but it was her request, as she also would want somewhere where she could write us some letters during her trip (which I would later put in the website for all our relatives to see.)

Unfortunately, I've encountered a problem where the page will load indefinitely after trying to implement a sort of "time tracking" function, where it would continuously check whether she is here or abroad.

Here's all my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Is grandma on a trip?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/health.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="headbar">
        <p id="namey" style="font-family: 'Roboto Slab';"><strong>Is grandma on a trip?</strong></p>
    </div>

    <div id="alertbox">
        <p id="status">Grandma is:</p>
        <p id="check">On a trip!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="flexy">
        <div class="timebox">
            <div id="countrytime">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timebox">
            <div id="fromtodep">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timebox">
            <div id="toarr">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexy">
        <btn class="butt"></btn>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fffef2;
    background-color: #d1b8e3;
}

.headbar {
    background-color: #926cad;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    max-height: 100px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.headbar p{
    font-size: 5vh;
    color: #fffef2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#alertbox {
   background-color: #e36b6b;
   width: 30%;
   height: 30%;
   max-height: 120px;
   max-width: 300px;
   margin: 30px;
   border-radius: 23px;
   font-family: Ubuntu;
   padding: 10px;
}

#alertbox p{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vh;
}
```

**JS**

```
function alertBox(){
    let d = new Date();
    let epoch = d.getTime();
    if (epoch > 1692136800000 && epoch < 1722038400000){
        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "On a trip!"
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "At home!"
    }
}

while (true){
    alertBox()
}
```

What could the problem be?

(Also, as a side note, I wanted for the box to change color to #6fb05f when she's going to be home, but I can't seem to do that, either)

Comment: "_What could the problem be?_" - You have an infinite (`while`-)loop.

Comment: _"What could the problem be?"_ - that you created an endless loop that never ends, with `while (true)`. This will block the whole browser UI. Go look into `setInterval` to create an interval that will check periodically.

Comment: @ivar I'd also need to implement a clock function, would an while loop be unreasonable as well then?

Comment: Just out of interest wouldn't _"as she also would want somewhere where she could write us some letters during her trip"_ indicate that she _was_ out of the country, and therefore you wouldn't need a separate check?

Comment: @Andy I think I will just do a separate HTML page and have a series of options (maybe through buttons) to redirect to one of them

Comment: _"I'd also need to implement a clock function, would an while loop be unreasonable as well then?"_ - yes, absolutely. You'll find lots and lots of examples and tutorials for JavaScript timers on the web, usually they also work with setInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you created an infinte while loop!

```
while (true) {
    alertBox()
}
```

is calling the alertBox function indefinitely. You will need to put it in intervals, for example check each second instead!

[mdn documentation about setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: You might want to include an example of an appropriate `setInterval` in your answer or, at the very least, link to the relevant documentation on MDN.

Comment: You are right @Andy , Linked a mdn article below!